# Reading file as bytes without newline or carriage return

Tags: java

I want to read an entire file into a byte array without newline or carriage return. I get 13,10 also in the byte array. Is there a way to read the entire file without newline or carriage return. 
I have used the below code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
numBytesRead=in.read(result, offset, noBytes);
```

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you'll have to filter that yourself:

```
byte[] raw = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
for (byte b : raw)
    if (b != 10 && b != 13)
        baos.write(b);
byte[] result = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there anything other than 10 & 13 I need to filter, as I am new to process file as bytes.

Comment: I don't know, you didn't provide enough information.. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to replace every 2nd and 3rd bytes in a record(size-160)  to space.

Comment: private void readInBytes(File file, int byteBlockSize) throws IOException {
  byte[] raw = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  int i = 0;
  for(byte b: raw) {
   if (i == 2 || i == 3) b = 32;
   if (b != 10 && b != 13 ) {
    i++;
   }
   if (i > byteBlockSize) i = 0;
   baos.write(b);
   System.out.print(b + ",");
  }
 }

Comment: So you have a file of records, where each is 160 bytes followed by CR LF?

Comment: yes, I have a file of record with 160 bytes and have to replace 2nd and 3rd byte of each record with space. The logic seems to work. One more detail. Is it possible to convert byte to char?

Comment: Yes, the easiest way is to use this String constructor: `new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)`..

Comment: Is there a limitation in Files.readAllBytes on the file size?

Comment: Yes - 2GB (all arrays in Java are limited to 2^31 elements).. If you have a file that big, you may want to process it record by record..