# Buffered Reader returns unexpected character from user input

Tags: java, user-input, bufferedreader, telnet

I have a multi-chat server client program and I am attempting to get input from a client in a telnet putty window. 
The prompt:

```
String login = "2-Enter Username and a password:";
        clientoutput.write((login).getBytes());
```

The user input:
[image]

This is read by a BufferedReader:

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientInput));
        String inputLine;
        String returnMessage;
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // Split input line with space as delimiter using import jar
            String[] words = StringUtils.split(inputLine);

            // Ensure we don't get a null pointer
            if (words != null && words.length > 0) {
                String command = words[0];

            if ("logoff".equalsIgnoreCase(command) || "q".equalsIgnoreCase(command) || "quit".equalsIgnoreCase(command)) {
                logOff();
                break;
                }else 
                    // Log user in
                    try {
                        clientLogIn(clientoutput, words);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
```

However the first word of user  input is consistently read as

> ÿû

: 
Eclipse console output:

> ***User ÿû has logged in***

So my question is where is this character **ÿû** coming from and is there a work around?

I am using WIndows 10 and Eclipse Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)
Build id: 20190314-1200

Additional info:
I've tried to capture the user input and directly print to console :

```
if (login.contains("ÿû")) {
            login = login.substring(1);
            System.out.println("New login after removal of unxepected char: " + login);
        } else {
            System.out.println("User eneterd login : " + login);

        }
```

Output:

> User entered login : -Enter Username and a password:
>
> ***User ÿû has logged in*** // after the first word has been taken

Comment: `while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {...` I think the interesting part comes after this

Comment: Anyway, since windows usually displays `0xFF` bytes as `'ÿ'` because of the default charset it uses, you're probably stumbling into [IAC commands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet#Telnet_data). I bet that if you discard that line, the next will contain what you expect.

Comment: Finally, you shouldn't consider telnet as a stream of lines, but as a stream of bytes, at least when you're writing a server.

Comment: Hi, not sure what you mean by discarding the line?

Comment: I mean if you don't care about accepting telnet commands, if a line starts with a `0xFF` byte, just ignore the line.

Comment: OK how do I implement this programmatically? I've tried searching string for the unexpected char and if present create a subtring to exclude same, but didnt work

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time to give a complete solution, but as a hint, this `login.contains("ÿû")` can't work because you're dealing in strings, when you want to deal with bytes. So, for example use `read` instead of `readLine` and check that you're not encountering a `0xFF` byte. There's plenty of code around that shows you how to deal with byte streams. If I'll find one I'll link it later.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47510977/133203) for example.

Comment: And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8512168/133203) about reconverting your byte array to string once you removed the unwanted ones.

Comment: Now that I think of it, since you're actually writing your own protocol, the problem seems to be that you're using the wrong *client* to test it. That is, telnet is not meant as a general TCP client. You may avoid the problem completely if you used something like `netcat` to test your code instead.

Comment: Thanks that works fine now,   can you post this as the answer so I can accept, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're actually writing your own protocol, the problem seems to be that you're using the wrong *client* to test your server.

That is, telnet is not meant as a general TCP client, as it sends commands alongside the actual data you're trying to send. Also, it works on bytes, not java strings (which you noticed when you tried to check for those weird chars at the beginning of the string).

You may avoid the problem completely if you used something like `netcat` to test your code instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. You got telnet protocol special bytes `0xff (IAC)` and `0xfb (WILL)`.
2. If you need to avoid it in your application, use this [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) (section you need is "TELNET COMMAND STRUCTURE") to skip protocol specific bytes.

Comment: Hi, I think I understand but how do I do this programmatically ?

Comment: @dancingbush technically, you need to work with bytes instead of lines. First of all you need to realize how telnet works to skip all protocol-specific bytes. BTW, you have written that you have a "multi-chat server client program", are you sure that you really need all that telnet specific things inside your code?

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov there's nothing telnet-specific in their code. Those commands are coming from PuTTY because, of course, it's a telnet client, not a client for their specific chat protocol.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, sure, it exactly what I meant, I think it's unnecesarry to deal with that bytes at all. dancingbush should just keep in mind that symbols are related with telnet protocol and won't appear in proper environment.

Comment: @AleksandrSemyannikov ok, I was thrown off by "are you sure that you really need all that telnet specific things inside your code?".